# What does this gdb output mean in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, error-handling

I'm in Xcode using the gdb debugger, I just don't understand the error messages I am getting, they seem to change after every run too.

Here is a snippet of the code that is being shown:

```
0x001e8975  <+0006>  sub    $0xc,%esp
0x001e8978  <+0009>  call   0x1e897d <prepareForMethodLookup+14>
0x001e897d  <+0014>  pop    %edi
0x001e897e  <+0015>  mov    0x8(%ebp),%esi
0x001e8981  <+0018>  mov    0x10(%esi),%eax
0x001e8984  <+0021>  and    $0xfffffffc,%eax

0x001e8987  <+0024>  cmpl   $0x0,(%eax)

0x001e898a  <+0027>  js     0x1e89d2 <prepareForMethodLookup+99>
0x001e898c  <+0029>  mov    0xfe697(%edi),%ebx
0x001e8992  <+0035>  cmpl   $0x0,(%ebx)
0x001e8995  <+0038>  je     0x1e89aa <prepareForMethodLookup+59>
0x001e8997  <+0040>  cmpl   $0x2,0x103df7(%edi)
```

The line in the middle there is where the green arrow seems to be pointing. I just don't fully understand what it means. I'd paste some of the code, but I'm not entairly sure where the actual problem is, and theres a lot of code. It's probably a noob question, or I may not have explained it very well, but I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: what code did u paste?

Comment: The code I have pasted appears when a certain action has been triggered in the app, resulting in some sort of error. On the left hand side, all it says is, Thread2 URLConnection 0 prepareForMethodLookup. Then in the main window, the code I pasted above, but a lot more. What I pasted was just part of it.

Comment: Zombies enabled? I'm sorry I'm still very new to this, I don't understand what that means.

Comment: turn on the zombies in your project so that you can get the readable error message on the console if your app crashes `Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme->Diagnostics->Enable Zombie Objects for objective-c`

Comment: Your comment indicates that you know what action is triggering the exception. Throw a breakpoint at the beginning of the method that results from that action, then step through the code until you can identify exactly which line is causing the exception. It's also helpful to add some NSLog statements to narrow down which methods are being called prior to the exception. This one lists the class and method name - add it to the beginning of any methods associated with the action, then see the results in the console: `NSLog(@"(%@ - %@) started", [self class], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));`

Comment: Cool thanks! I did that, and now I can see a readable error message. This is what it is: [CFURL absoluteURL]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xe7a75a0 do you know of a quick way of finding out where in the code I should be looking?

Comment: Thanks David, I'll give that a go and see what happens!

Comment: type absoluteURL in search editor, that is where u are making a mistake...

Comment: I did a search for absoluteURL and all it seems to bring back is code in the ASIHttp lib I am using. Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have exception breakpoints enabled?

Press CMD-6 while in XCode

This should change you from project explorer to breakpoints on your left hand tab

Click the little + at the bottom left of the page and "Add Exception Breakpoint", this adds a breakpoint for all exceptions that happen in the app.

I'm not sure why they're not on by default, it's a little annoying!

This may help you track down the problem you're facing.

Comment: Thanks, I have enabled that now,and it does show a little more detail in the console, but I'm still having a hard time trying to track down where in the code I need to change. I'm still getting: `[CFURL absoluteURL]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xa37d780`

Comment: Sounds like something is not being retained, probably an NSURL instance that you're calling [NSURL absoluteURL] on... Are you calling this function anywhere in your code?

Comment: I did a search through all the code, and the only two instances of `absoluteURL` were in ASIHttp: `NSArray *cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookiesForURL:[[self url] absoluteURL]];` and `[self setRedirectURL:[[NSURL URLWithString:[responseHeaders valueForKey:@"Location"] relativeToURL:[self url]] absoluteURL]];`

Comment: I'm not sure, might be worth posting another question with the ASI code that's going wrong, someone else may be able to help.